# Mastodon with Pidgin?

Tags: plugins, pidgin

I'm trying Mastodon. According to [the Mastodon Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastodon_(software)),

> The service is interoperable with the federated social network GNU
>   social and other OStatus platforms.

Now Pidgin has the [Twitter Protocol plugin](https://github.com/mikeage/prpltwtr) that claims to work with Status.net as well (Which became GNU Social), but when set to use my Mastodon account, it just crashed Pidgin.

Is it maybe that I'm just missing some settings that could make this work, or there is no way to get Pidgin to work with Mastodon?

Comment: Programs don't crash intentionally. If your configuration causes the plugin to crash, wouldn't you assume that the plugin (or Pidgin itself) simply has [unfixed bugs](https://github.com/mikeage/prpltwtr/issues/32)?

Comment: TBH I didn't browse through all the closed issues.(And for some reason it didn't turn up in Google either.) Would you word this as a proper answer I'd be willing to provide the fake internet points for it though, @grawity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no Mastadon plugin for Pidgin, which would be listed on https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/ThirdPartyPlugins#AdditionalProtocols

The quote about interoperability only refers to server-to-server federation, the client-side is a totally different protocol.  As mentioned at https://github.com/tootsuite/mastodon/issues/176 the core Mastadon author is opposed to client interoperability